# How to save CKEDITOR html to Database?

Tags: iframe, ckeditor, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I'm trying to save CKEDITOR tags to database without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `htmlspecialchars()`, but you need using PDO when storing a data into server. Make sure that your textarea HTML tag correctly as:

`<textarea class="ckeditor"><?php echo $your_value_from_db; ?></textarea>`